# Java popup loading

Tags: java, swing

Does anybody have Java popup loading dialog ?
Or can anybody tell me how to program this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need a plain MessageDialog with an "i" for information icon:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "This is the message...", "Title");
```

frame is the top level container you want to bind this dialog to modally. You can use null if you want, then it will show up accordingly to the window system.

You can add a fourth argument:
 `JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE`, `JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE`, `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE` or `JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE` the latter goes with a fifth argument for your own Icon.

Java tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: The ProgressMonitorInputStream mentioned in that link is *especially* well suited to 'loading' resources (if that is what the OP meant).

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at [How to make dialogs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).